# How to save custom settings api fields with custom section fuction

Tags: options, theme-options, settings-api

I am creating wordpress theme on a single options page. I have customized the default do_settings_fields and do_settings_sections functions. my fields are displaying fine but when i am trying to save it, It won't save.

```
function amna_theme_options_page () {
wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-options-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/admin/assets/css/theme-options-css.css' );
settings_errors(); 
?>
<div class="wrap flex-tab">
    <form action='' method='post' class="amna-fields">
        <?php 
        amna_do_settings_fields('amna-fields-group', 'theme_amna');
        amna_do_settings_sections('theme_amna'); 
        
        submit_button();
        ?>
    </form>
</div>
<?php }
```

And these are the functions i have override to display fields

```
function amna_do_settings_sections($page) {
global $wp_settings_sections, $wp_settings_fields;

if ( !isset($wp_settings_sections) || !isset($wp_settings_sections[$page]) )
    return;

foreach( (array) $wp_settings_sections[$page] as $section ) {
    echo "<h3>{$section['title']}</h3>\n";
    call_user_func($section['callback'], $section);
    if ( !isset($wp_settings_fields) ||
         !isset($wp_settings_fields[$page]) ||
         !isset($wp_settings_fields[$page][$section['id']]) )
            continue;
    echo '<div class="settings-form-wrapper">';
    amna_do_settings_fields($page, $section['id']);
    echo '</div>';
}
}

function amna_do_settings_fields($page, $section) {
global $wp_settings_fields;

if ( ! isset( $wp_settings_fields[ $page ][ $section ] ) ) {
    return;
}

foreach ( (array) $wp_settings_fields[$page][$section] as $field ) { ?>
    <div class="settings-form-row flex-tab">
        
        <?php if ( !empty($field['args']['label_for']) )
            echo '<p><label for="' . $field['args']['label_for'] . '">' .
                $field['title'] . '</label><br />';
        else
        call_user_func($field['callback'], $field['args']);
        echo '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
}
```

Comment: Your form should submit to `options.php` and there should be a call to [`register_setting()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/) in your code.

Comment: i added the options.php on form action but it was redirected on the options.php @SallyCJ

Comment: Redirected to where? Can you show your full code?

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ i have figure out the issue. Posting my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I could understand why you "customized" (i.e. use your own version of) the [`do_settings_sections()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_settings_sections/) and [`do_settings_fields()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_settings_fields/) functions — because you want to use `div` and not `table`, right?

But if it's just about styling, you could actually just use CSS to style the table so that it doesn't look like a table; however, you'll have to try doing that on your own. And WordPress may change the global variables (their name and/or data structure) in the future, so just keep that in mind, i.e. you'll have to make sure that your code is in sync with the original functions in the current WordPress release.

### Making your form works properly (e.g. the fields are saved in the correct database option)

As I said in the comments, your form should submit to `options.php` (i.e. `<form action="options.php" ...>`) and call [`register_setting()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/) in your code to register your form or its settings group, and the *database* option (the second parameter for that function).

And in the `amna_theme_options_page()`, there's no need to call the `amna_do_settings_fields()` because it's already being called in and should only be called in `amna_do_settings_sections()` which renders all the fields for your settings form, whereby each field should belong in a specific section. So instead, call [`settings_fields()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/settings_fields/) so that WordPress knows what the options/settings page is and the database option to be updated:

```php
settings_fields( 'amna-fields-group' );                       // do this
//amna_do_settings_fields('amna-fields-group', 'theme_amna'); // not this
```

Another issue I noticed is that in `amna_do_settings_fields()`, if the `label_for` arg is *not* empty, then the field is not actually going to be rendered because the `call_user_func()` is only being called in the `else` part.

So it should be more like so:

```php
echo '<p>';
if ( ! empty( $field['args']['label_for'] ) ) {
    echo '<label for="' . esc_attr( $field['args']['label_for'] ) . '">' . $field['title'] . '</label>';
} else {
    echo $field['title'];
}

call_user_func( $field['callback'], $field['args'] );
echo '</p>';
```

Additionally, you should pass the slug of your settings page to [`settings_errors()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/settings_errors/), e.g. `settings_errors( 'theme_amna' );` if the slug is `theme_amna`. And if you don't do that, then you'd likely see the same settings errors/messages printed *twice*.

Also, admin stylesheet files (`.css`) should be enqueued via the [`admin_enqueue_scripts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/). For example, to enqueue only on your settings page:

```php
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_load_styles' );
function my_plugin_load_styles( $hook_suffix ) {
    if ( $hook_suffix === get_plugin_page_hook( 'theme_amna', '' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-options-css',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/admin/assets/css/theme-options-css.css' );
    }
}
```

### Working Example

[You can find it on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/5ally/776c5291b0f826ea17ef4b8467c12c48).

It's a full working example which gives you a settings page at *Settings → Test*.

Comment: This is not the response of my question. my question was , i have write the custom code for do_settings_fields and do_settings_sections functions. In this case we dont need to call options.php but the function should submit the data on save changes button. So need to write the code for save changes button.

Comment: Well, you're just changing the table to `div` and the rest should still follow the settings API methods like calling `settings_field()` and submitting to `options.php` so that you would not need to manually call `update_option()`. That's what I mean by "proper". After all, the `amna_do_settings_sections()` already calls `amna_do_settings_fields()`, so why call it manually? Settings fields should belong in their own settings section, no?

Comment: if you click on save changes button settings fields and settings section will not find the update_options function because update options was called and attached with save changes buttons, same as the error_message();. so you will have to write the functions for both of it.

Comment: See the revised answer and try the sample plugin. I hope that helps?

Comment: Thank you, just update the settings_fields( 'amna-fields-group' ); and options.php that work fine. but error is not longer working. can you just help me how can i submit fields data by ajax?

Comment: "error is not longer working" - what error? But I've already given you a sample plugin that should work in that the fields are being saved properly, so about the AJAX, please ask that in another post. However, do take time to read the documentation in the [plugin developer handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/) and/or the [REST API handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) before asking your question.

Comment: error notification mean, settings_errors( 'theme_amna' ); this is not longer showing the success message, dont know why. and here is the question asked for ajax https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/370176/how-to-submit-the-settings-api-data-by-ajax-on-theme-options-page.

Comment: And are you sure the settings page slug is actually `theme_amna` ? Did you try my sample plugin? Did it work?

Comment: if the page settings were different , form will not save the data but actually it is saving. the only thing error is not showing. but i really dont care about it because i want to save data by ajax.

Comment: Alright then. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. and can you please have a look of the question i asked?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting answer of my own question because of people reference and did not find solution anywhere.

Basically if you are changing default do_settings_section(); and do_settings_fields(); the submit button will not find where to submit data because default function was override with new one. In Such case you will have to write you submit button function to execute the code and save the fields data into the database.

So instead of submit_button(); i have write my button

```
<p class="submit"><input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e( 'Save changes', 'amna_save_settings' ); ?>" /></p>
```

Then on save button code

```
if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && (isset($_POST['amna_fields']))) {
            update_site_option( 'amna_fields', $_POST['amna_fields'] );
}
```